# How to repaint certain part of panel / or use two panels on top of each other with the top one having transparent background?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a C# WinForms project where I have to paint some things on my panel. I load in a grid from a file that translates to squares that are painted on the panel. Then I load in a file with dots that are then painted on top of the squares.

I then have a function that moves the dots around. But the repaint function is called every tick which causes the whole grid to flicker continously because it is painted so quick after each other.

How do I make it so that only the dots are repainted?

The **repaint** and **paint** functions are as follows:

```
private void Repaint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GridPanel.Invalidate();
}

private void GridPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
  if ((GridPanel.Width != grid.Width || GridPanel.Height != grid.Height)) 
  {
    grid.Height = GridPanel.Height;
    grid.Width = GridPanel.Width;
    grid.setDimensions();
  }

  Graphics g = e.Graphics;
  g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(0, 0, grid.Width, grid.Height));

  foreach(Square square in grid.Squares) 
  {
    if (square.Letter != '_') 
    {
      SolidBrush color = new SolidBrush(square.Color);
      g.FillRectangle(color, new Rectangle(square.X * grid.squareWidth, square.Y * grid.squareHeight, grid.squareWidth, grid.squareHeight));
    }
  }

  foreach(Artist artist in grid.Artists) 
  {
    SolidBrush color = new SolidBrush(artist.Color);
    g.FillRectangle(color, new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(artist.X * grid.squareWidth), Convert.ToInt32(artist.Y * grid.squareHeight), grid.artistWidth, grid.artistHeight));
  }
}
```

I also tried to use a second panel for the dots so I only have to repaint that one. But I cant get a transparent background working on the second panel, so the first panel is not visible this way.

Somebody knows a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Try drawing the grid from the file to a Bitmap and set that as the background of the panel, then only draw the dots in the Paint event. Did you enable double buffering for your panel?

Comment: I was able to create a double buffered panel. This fixes the flickering issue completely.